# Reload page on add or edit of Jqgrid submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid on my page which i use for adding data. I use the dialog method to add but when the user submits, i want to refresh the entire page, not just the grid.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

```
$("#addSpecialItem").click(function () {
            jQuery("#specialItemGrid").jqGrid('editGridRow', "new",
                { height: 380,
                    addCaption: "Special Item",
                    bSubmit: "Add to Order",
                    closeAfterAdd: true,
                    afterRefresh: function () {
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                });
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

I was using afterRefresh instead of afterSubmit, this now reload the page

```
afterSubmit: function () {
                        location.reload(true);
                    }
```

Comment: Thanks , It's Work

Answer (score 0):

Try using `location.reload()` in your callback

Optionally you can use `location.reload(true)` to make sure that the page is loaded afresh from the server rather than the browser cache