# I need jqgrid to refresh the entire page, not just the grid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I need jqgrid to refresh the entire page, not just the grid

I have a jqgrid that displays the job details of auto repairs. Right now, I have the grid reloading using the following script and I need to change it so that it refreshes the entire page so that the subtotal and total fields (that sit outside of the grid) update. Here is my relevant code, any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
    var editOptions = {
        keys: true,
        successfunc: function () {
            var $self = $(this);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $self.trigger("reloadGrid");
            }, 50);
        }
    };

      $grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {add: false, edit: false, del: true, search:false},{reloadAfterSubmit:true,afterSubmit:commonSubmit,closeAfterEdit:true,width:"400"},{reloadAfterSubmit:true,afterSubmit:commonSubmit,closeAfterAdd:false,width:"400"},{url:"editGrid.cfc?method=delUser",closeAfterDelete:true,reloadAftersubmit:false,afterSubmit:commonSubmit,caption:"Delete",msg:"Delete selected",width:"400"});

      $grid.jqGrid('inlineNav', '#pager', {addParams:{position:"last",addRowParams:editOptions},editRowParams:editOptions});
  });
```

Comment: By the way, I tried changing $self.trigger("reloadGrid"); to $self.trigger("location.reload ()"); but that just makes the new row disappear until I refresh the page manually using F5. (I also tried resetForm() and got the same results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need to reload of the whole current HTML page you can call `location.reload();` or `location.reload(true);`.

If you need just to refresh some elements on the page which are outside of grid you can include the values (subtotal and total) in the server response and fill the value inside of `loadComplete` or `beforeProcessing` callback. Inside of both `loadComplete` and `beforeProcessing` the first parameter `data` contains full server response. So you can get from the response the required values (subtotal and total) and use jQuery.val or some other method to modify the outside element of the page.

Comment: Thank you Oleg. I tried using location.reload() and when I changed it, the grid would refresh to the original state (without the new row) until I manually hit F5 and then it re-appears. The funny thing is, on the deletes, it's calling a function called commonSubmit which includes the resetForm() command and it works fine when deleting a row. It only seems to be affected when it's inside the editOptions variable. I've tried everything I could think of for the last 2 days and can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: @RaymondMeade: You are welcome! Do you used `location.reload();` or `location.reload(true);`. The last one should don't use the local cache and reload the page from the server. It could be additionally important how you filled the grid. HTTP response can contains HTTP cache option in the HTTP header. For example I set typically `Cache-Control: private, max-age=0` in the server response with the JSON data for the grid.

Comment: I've tried it both ways. I even tried window.location.reload(true) and resetForm(). Nothing seems to work there except for reloadGrid. I think the problem is somewhere in the editOptions variable but I don't know the syntax of javascript or jquery well enough to figure it out. (this is my very first time using jquery or jqgrid)

Comment: @Raymond, I now have the same problem here. May I know do you figure it out?

Comment: @zhihong: If you look at the profile of Raymond you will see "Last seen Dec 4 '14 at 21:29". So I don't recommend you to wait for his answer. You should just try my recommendations and use `location.reload();` or `location.reload(true);` and to see the results.

Comment: @Oleg, thanks for your quick answer, I already tried it according the post based on your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430847/reload-page-on-add-or-edit-of-jqgrid-submit, I use afterSubmit: function(){location.reload(true);}, but still only the grid is reloaded, the newly added row is not in the table. What else do you think I can try?

Comment: @zhihong: `location.reload(true);` reloads the whole page. You can press "F5" in web browser to compare the results. I suppose that you have some problems with caching of previous response from the server with jqGrid data.

Comment: @Oleg, magic,now it works. I see I missed the "," just now, so the refresh dose not work. Now, everything works OK, thanks very much for all your help :)